# Windows 2003 64 bit R2 Edition slow I/O Performance

Tags: wcf

We have developed and deployed WCF services on Windows 2003 64 bit R2 edition with 4 GB RAM. The database we are using is Firebird 1.5/2.x. My application database operations like plain select or insert causes too much delays on the server when compared to Windows xp. We hosted the WCF as WoW in IIS (running 32 bit mode applications in 64 bit server).

We have earlier used Developer Express XPO (Object Relational Mapper) and even after we converted those queries to plain ADO.NET, no significant improvement.

When checked through dotTrace profiler, it appears that the Receive operation of System.Net.Socket.Receive (Bye[], Int32...) operation causes the delay for around 4 seconds and it appears that it could be because of some I/O or TCP delay.

I have read some posts about reducing the TCPAckFrequency delay from 200 ms to instant and not sure if that helps here.

Not every INSERT/SELECT operations are delayed but most of them are delayed when compared to Win XP with 1 GB RAM

Comment: Yes. I appreciate your time. Let me briefly explain the development and deployment environments here:


General architecture: Our app is a desktop application using heavily developer express controls (Winform and WPF) (http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms) and all the business, data access logic hosted as WCF services in IIS. For all document management operations to manage the image or other media files, we do use WebDAV.

Comment: On the sevrer side, most of the database access controlled by Developer express Object relational wrapper XPO http://www.devexpress.com/products/NET/ORM/. The datastore is being managed in the Firebird 1.5/2.x (http://www.firebirdsql.org/). We do see some latency with XPO and because of some contraints with their API, in certain places we have moved our data access logic to plain ADO.NET calls sacrificing database independency feature.

.NET Framework 3.5, IIS, WCF, WinForms/WPF and WebDAV

Comment: Development environment: Win XP, Visual Studio 2008, .NET 3.5, IIS 5.0, 32 bit 

Deployment environment Server : Windows 2003 64 bit R2 edition, Windows 2008 84 bit, Windows 7 64/32bit
Workstations: Win XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7 32 bit.

In most of the deployment environment, we have both the database and application server hosted in the same machine as only maximum of 10 users using the application concurrently. All the WCF services hosted as WoW model in 64 bit environments.

Comment: Investigations done:

With our development environment, most of the operations taking less time but on production environments are taking more time. Using dotTrace and EQATEC profilers, it appears that the database calls taking more time compared to our development environment.

Comment: We have created some test clients to get rid off other factors such as WCF, IIS and even with that direct ADO.NET usage. results like plain simple inserts taking around 300 to 500 ms and multiple select and inserts of this kind cause a delay of over 3-5 seconds which is not acceptable in production environment. For example, if the insert takes 4 seconds, almost 80% of time 3 seconds actually in the mscorblib function System.Net.Socket.Receive(Byte[], Int32,Int32,SocketFlag, SocterError&) calls to get the identity key returned back from the database server for every insert.

Comment: There were some posts related to tune TCP/IP parameters TCPAckFrequency not sure if that helps us.
We have migrated Firebird to 2.5 and increased database cache, nothing of much help. There is no other programs sharing the CPU or memory and all the production class machines with Xeon Processor with 4/8 GB RAM. There is no traffic monitoring tools like virus scanners running which could possibly affect the performance.
The insert and select operations become worse with the tables having more no. of records. Few tables has more than 80K rows too and most of the other tables having around 5K rows

Comment: Firebird uses the default port 3050

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain your environment a bit more please? The Windows XP machine sounds like it was a development machine with both Database and Server code on the same machine?

Also, the windows server setup I assume you have a separate application server and database server?

I don't know what Firebird is and have no experience with that. Does it use the same ports as SQL Server?

Comment: Yes. I appreciate your time. Let me briefly explain the development and deployment environments here:


General architecture: Our app is a desktop application using heavily developer express controls (Winform and WPF) (http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms) and all the business, data access logic hosted as WCF services in IIS. For all document management operations to manage the image or other media files, we do use WebDAV.

Comment: So it looks like the WinXP installation is a local dev instance with the Database running on the same server as the service instances? If this is correct, it could potentially explain why you see no degradation in this scenario as it does not have to cross firewalls when accessing the SQL instance.In the Windows Server scenario, the  application server and the Db are on separate machines thus it could be an issue with ports & general network comms between the server. You could use a tool like Wireshark to capture to communications between these machines and look for excessive failures/retries.